# Why can a `Record<string, any>` be assigned to a `Record<number, any>` without type errors?

Tags: typescript, polymorphism

The following assignment produces a type error:

```js
const t: Record<number, any> = { key: 'value'}
```

This is expected behavior. However, the following assignment, unexpectedly, does not produce a type error.

```js
const c: Record<string, any> = { key: 'value'}
const t: Record<number, any> = c
```

How come? I suspect that this has something to do with the way in which polymorphism works on `Record`, but I can't find any documentation on this.

Comment: It's more to do with index type to which TS resolves `Record` - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures

Comment: This has little to do with `Record` per se and a lot to do with [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) only applying to object literals.  There are many situations in which `const foo: Foo = {bar: 123}` fails but `const bar = {bar: 123}; const foo: Foo = bar;` succeeds.  I'm happy to write up an answer, but I'm wondering if this should just be marked as a duplicate of an existing question regarding excess property errors.

Comment: ...not that I've found a good existing question that fits this.  I guess I'll write up an answer if nobody gets here first (and anyone who does is more than welcome to do so!)

Comment: @jcalz I'm not sure that this is explained by excess property checks. The question still stands in the case of a function `function f(_: Record<number, any>): void {}` which will accept without type errors a `Record<string, any>` whether passed in as a literal or as a value bound to a name.

Comment: [Not according to this it doesn't](https://tsplay.dev/wRJBEw).  Can you elaborate on what you mean? Maybe I'm misunderstanding.